# Freeing dynamically allocated memory in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

Coming back to some C code I wrote a few years ago and I feel it ought to be leaking memory, but I can find no sign that is it and I would like to check my assumptions.

I have a structure like this:

```
struct BitArray {
   ....
   char *bits;
   ....
}
```

`bits` is allocated dynamically like this:

```
bArray->bits = (char *)calloc(1, 1 << shiftNumber);
```

And `free`-ed like this:

```
free(nextBA->bits);
```

But shouldn't that leak memory - ie it will only `free` the very first `char` that `bits` points to? What is the correct way to `free` the memory allocated in this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it won't leak memory. In fact this is all good.

You are passing something that is earlier passed by memory management function (`calloc` here). So it's ok.

From [**standard 7.22.3.1**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.3p1) the caution

> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be
>   deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is
>   a null pointer, no action occurs. ***Otherwise, if the argument does not
>   match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function***, or
>   if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the
>   behavior is undefined.

Well here this is ***certainly*** not the case. So it's alright.

#### it will only free the very first char that bits points to?

No it will `free` the allocated chunk.

The way you have done is the right way.

Comment: Thanks, been writing too much C++ lately :-)

Comment: What's writing in C++ got to do with it?   If you use `calloc()` and `free()` in C++ in this way, the same answer applies.

Comment: Because modern C++ is all about passing references and not about new/delete